# How to denny whitespaces in regex when use FOS User Bundle?

Tags: php, regex, symfony-2.8

I used `^[a-zA-Z0-9]$` as regex for password and when I insert whitespaces and submit the form a password is allowed.

`@Assert\NotBlank()` is output message 'Password should not be blank'.

How can I fix this in regex?

Comment: Well, I think you meant to use `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$` at least (to allow 0+ characters, you need `*`).

Comment: Of course, excuse me. But I don't understand why password is allowed with any whitespaces.

Comment: Can you include the actual code that's doing the validating?

Comment: /**
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/",

     *     message="Password contains letters and numbers."
     * )
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $password;

Comment: Insert few whitespaces -> Password is allowed